# Julia MethodError: no method matching (::Dense{typeof(logistic),CuArray{Float32,2,Nothing},CuArray{Float32,1,Nothing}})(::Float32)

Tags: julia, julia-gpu

I have the following training data in CuArrays.

```
X: 300×8544 CuArray{Float32,2,Nothing}
y: 5×8544 Flux.OneHotMatrix{CuArray{Flux.OneHotVector,1,Nothing}}
```

and I have the following model I want to train:

```
# define activation
logistic(x) = 1. / (1 .+ exp.(-x))

# first define a 2-layer MLP model
model = Chain(Dense(300, 64, logistic),
          Dense(64, c),
          softmax) |> gpu

# define the loss
loss(x, y) = Flux.crossentropy(model(x), y)

# define the optimiser
optimiser = ADAM()
```

but if I do

```
Flux.train!(loss, params(model), zip(X, y), optimiser)
```

I get the following error:

```
MethodError: no method matching (::Dense{typeof(logistic),CuArray{Float32,2,Nothing},CuArray{Float32,1,Nothing}})(::Float32)
```

How should I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

@D.Danier Please provide minimal working examples (MWE), that means complete code that people can copy and paste and run. Below is an example

```
#Pkg.activate("c:/scratch/flux-test")

using CuArrays, Flux
CuArrays.allowscalar(false)

# define activation
# you don't the broadcast dots
logistic(x) = 1 / (1 + exp(-x))

# ensure your code works on GPU
CuArrays.@cufunc logistic(x) = 1 / (1 + exp(-x))

X = cu(rand(300, 8544))
y = cu(rand(5, 8544))
c = 5

# first define a 2-layer MLP model
model = Chain(Dense(300, 64, logistic),
          Dense(64, c),
          softmax) |> gpu

# define the loss
loss(x, y) = Flux.crossentropy(model(x), y) |> gpu

model(X)

# define the optimiser
optimiser = ADAM()

loss(X, y)

Flux.train!(loss, params(model), zip(eachcol(X), eachcol(y)), optimiser)
```

When you `Flux.train!`, you must tell `Flux` that you want to pair up the columns of `X` and `y` to compute the loss. BTW, this is probably less than ideal as it's computing too many iterations. You may want to group them up into mini-batches. Or if your problem is genuinely this small, then you can want to compute the whole thing in one go e.g.

```
Flux.train!(loss, params(model), (X, y), optimiser)
```

which basically say compute the loss based on the whole of `X` and `y`.